# listView scroll up/down automatically in Android

Tags: android, listview

Hi i want to implement a list view that scroll up/down automatically. I used scroll by method with timer. But it was not getting smooth onclick event. The list view has only ten list items. Please help me how can i achieve this.

Comment: You mean scroll to the bottom; wait a little then scroll back up? or scroll to a specific position?

Comment: yes automatically start scrolling to bottom at a slow speed. Once reach at the bottom, start scrolling towards the 1st item

Answer (score 1):

Android actually has a widget for this. It's called `ListViewAutoScrollHelper` and it's a part of the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

A simple implementation  would look something like this:

```
    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    final ListViewAutoScrollHelper scrollHelper = new ListViewAutoScrollHelper(list);
    scrollHelper.setEnabled(true);
    list.setOnTouchListener(scrollHelper);
```

To begin scrolling, touch your finger near the top (to scroll up) or bottom (to scroll down) edge of the screen and keep it pressed for the amount of time you'd like to remain scrolling.

Comment: I tried this.But its not a successful attempt.What i want that the list should automatically start scrolling to bottom at a slow speed. Once reach at the bottom, start scrolling towards the 1st item

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Timer use Async task , then scroll your ListView items in the method publish progress of AsyncTask.

```
 private class MyTimer extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {
 protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... int) 
 {
          while(true)
          {
             publishProgress(0);
             try
             {
               Thread.sleep(2000);
              }
            catch (Exception e)
           {

           }

         }          

     return 0;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) 
 {
   //Scroll Your ListView   
 }
```

}